# How to say "do you identify with"?

Tags: words, colloquial-language

I want to talk about pop culture and anime with my friends in the near future but I definitely don't have the vocabulary.

The dictionary on "to identify" was rather unhelpful as there are other meanings of the verb in English.

How can I ask someone

> Do you identify with the main character?

I guess for "main character" I can say 主人公. That was not so hard to find in the dictionary.

Comment: Can you enlighten this (English-)illiterate? By "to identify with" do you mean 2 of this -> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identify ?

Comment: @eltonjohn 'to understand the character's feelings', 「自分はこのキャラクターと同じだ」という気持ちかな？

Comment: @oals: Thanks. Then she means 2.2 of http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identify , I guess.

Comment: @eltonjohn Yes, more like 2. The precise meaning is that you feel that you are like the main character (or the main character is like you). I think this is not so clearly put in the Oxford dictionary.

Comment: Yes, it is, sorry, only saw 2.2 just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Provided you mean 2.2 of this -> http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/identify by "to identify with", I would say

> 主人公に共{きょう}感{かん}できる？　or 　主人公に感{かん}情{じょう}移{い}入{にゅう}できる？

Caveat: the above are not verbatim translations.

Comment: Actually, what is the word for "character"? Like if I want to ask "What's your favourite character?"? This word has a gazillion of meanings in English :-/

Comment: @user213845: in this case I would say the word for "character" is "登{とう}場{じょう}人{じん}物{ぶつ}".　So,  "What's your favourite character?" would translate into "お気{き}に入{い}りの登場人物は誰{だれ}？".